# i am struggling to add active class to my navigation menus with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i used ajax on my site to load pages dynamically and  add hashes to urls to preserve history and browser back button, and for this i am using `jquery bbq` plugin that is based on `html5 history api` and i have to say everything working fine except one issue and that is **active class** to current link.

i have two navigation **main menu** which is only on homepage and a second one is included on every page with php `include` function and its kind of a subnav of main menu.

as i said my problem is **how to add active class to any link that is clicked so its look different from others and users should know where they are right now!**

i tried different techniques but those only works with `main menu` and some kind of problem with `secondary nav` for better understanding please watch this [video](https://youtu.be/8VFB33w2Iaw)

as you can see in the video it works fine on `main menu` but only adds class to the `secondary menu` after click once on any link then click another link and then click back to original link, moreover when i refresh it removes the active class.

here is my code.

**main menu**

```
<div id="vertical-menu">
    <!--<h2 class="logo">LOGO</h2>-->
    <div class="logo">
        <span class="arcd-male97"></span> 
        <h2 class="logo-name">AMR</h2>
        <h6 class="logo-desc">ARCADE MUSIC REPOSITORY</h6>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul id='menu' class="menu-items">
            <li><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page0.php"><i class="arcd-archive"></i></br>Browse</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Top_albums/Top_albums_Page0.php"><i class="arcd-music97"></i></br>Top albums</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Top_artists/Top_artists_Page0.php" ><i class="arcd-microphone52"></i></br>Top artists</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Top_lists/Top_lists_Page0.php" ><i class="arcd-numbered8"></i></br>Top lists</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Charts/Charts_Page0.php" ><i class="arcd-rising9"></i></br>Charts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**secondary navbar**

```
<div class="header_container" id="header_container"> <!--start header div-->
    <div id="header_titles">
        <h1 class="browse-heading">BROWSE</h1>
        <h2 class="browse-subheading">GENRES & MOODS</h2>
    </div> 
</div> <!--end header div-->  

<div id="tabnav_container"> <!--start tabnav_container-->
    <div class="navtab_background"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul id="tabnav">
            <li class="pop_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page1.php"><i class="arcd-microphone352"></i>pop</a></li>
            <li class="country_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page2.php"><i class="arcd-guitarcountry"></i>country</a></li>
            <li class="rock_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page3.php"><i class="arcd-electricclone"></i>rock</a></li>
            <li class="blues_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page4.php"><i class="arcd-harmonicblues"></i>blues</a></li>
            <li class="edm_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page5.php"><i class="arcd-disc62edm"></i>edm</a></li>
            <li class="jazz_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page6.php"><i class="arcd-trumpet12jazz"></i>jazz</a></li>
            <li class="rnb_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page7.php"><i class="arcd-mic102"></i>r&b</a></li>
            <li class="hip-hop_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page8.php"><i class="arcd-musicplayer1hiphop"></i>hip hop</a></li>
            <li class="reggae_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page9.php"><i class="arcd-mic102"></i>reggae</a></li>
            <li class="classical_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page10.php"><i class="arcd-violin62classical"></i>classical</a></li>
            <li class="folk_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page11.php"><i class="arcd-guitar92folk"></i>folk</a></li>
            <li class="soul_tab"><a href="#Browse/Browse_Page12.php"><i class="arcd-mic102"></i>soul</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div><!--end tabnav_container-->
```

**and this is ajax script**

```
$(function() { 
    // Keep a mapping of url-to-container for caching purposes.
    var cache = {
        // If url is '' (no fragment), display this div's content.
        '': $('#default-homepage-contents')
    };

    // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the history state changes,
    // gets the url from the hash and displays either our cached content or fetches
    // new content to be displayed.
    $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {

        // Get the hash (fragment) as a string, with any leading # removed. Note that
        // in jQuery 1.4, you should use e.fragment instead of $.param.fragment().
        var url = $.param.fragment();

        // Hide any visible ajax content.
        $( '#main-container' ).children( ':visible' ).hide();

        if ( cache[ url ] ) {
            // Since the element is already in the cache, it doesn't need to be
            // created, so instead of creating it again, let's just show it!
            cache[ url ].fadeIn(1000);

        } else {
            // Show "loading" content while AJAX content loads.
            $( '#loading' ).delay(500).show();

            // Create container for this url's content and store a reference to it in
            // the cache.
            cache[ url ] = $( '<div class="bbq-item"/>' )

            // Append the content container to the parent container.
            .appendTo( '#main-container' )

            // Load external content via AJAX. Note that in order to keep this
            // example streamlined, only the content in .infobox is shown. You'll
            // want to change this based on your needs.
            .load( url, function() {
                // Content loaded, hide "loading" content.
                $( '#loading' ).fadeOut(1000);
            });
        }
    })

    // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
    // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
    $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
});
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with new browsers and found this, I think the only correctly working plugin: [jquery address](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address)
and docs are here: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/#api-reference example usage is

```
$(function() {
    //push it to history
    $('#tabnav > li').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.address.parameter("browse", $(this).attr("href"), false);
    });

    //catch changes
    $.address.change(function () {
        $.each($.address.parameterNames(), function (index, value) {
            url = $.address.parameter(value);
            $('a[href="'+url+'"]').addClass('active');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for that but did i need to change my markup for this plugin to work or is ok with this?

Comment: it should be ok, but it will be better if you remove .php from uri string, it is not nice :)

Comment: or to change event you can catch exact parameter, for example `var url = $.address.parameter("browse");` so you don't have to change anything in html code